# Angular Material MatFormField appearance="fill" theming questions

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have a question dealing with Angular Material theming, specifically the MatFormField directive. Probably around Material v6, I found that the `matFormField` directive has new options such as `appearance="fill"` and `appearance="outline"`, I have found the `appearance="fill"` useful, but I'd like to know how to change the background color, of the fill being used.

I have tried a few approaches such as,

```
<input class="w-100 bg-white form-control" #tileFilter 
          [formControl]="filterBy" 
          [matAutocomplete]="spiritilesAutocomplete"
          [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
          placeholder="Search by... Keyword, Author, Title, Story, etc."
          >
```

I've also tried selecting

```
mat-form-field .mat-form-field-flex{
    background-color: white; 
}
```

and many other variations of selecting and styling mat-form-field in particular, but I cannot find the css selector nor, an api reference to the background color in the documentation. I see that Material allows theming of the underlined portion and the label, but I would like to target specifically the background-color. Could anyone please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 6):

In this case, use ng-deep in your component css file.

```
::ng-deep {
  .mat-form-field .mat-form-field-flex{
    background-color: white; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Won't this change the background of every mat-form-field in the UI? I usually do something like `:host ::ng-deep` so that angular continues to limit it to the component as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-fill .mat-form-field-flex {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `!important` to the background-color value in order to make it work:

```
.mat-form-field-flex {
    background-color: white !important;
}
```

Comment: This didn't wind up working for me, I tried this beforehand to, using the code
`mat-form-field .mat-form-field-flex{
background-color: white !important;
}`

Comment: Not if your class is defined in your global style sheet. That's why I asked where the code was defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Angular ~v14 (not sure the exact versions compatible), this CSS code should work:

```css
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-fill .mat-form-field-flex {
  background-color: white;
}
```

You'll need to replace the part '*.mat-form-field-appearance-fill*' with your element's class.

However, somewhere around v16 (not sure exactly when) that code stopped working, and this works now for me instead:

```css
::ng-deep .mat-mdc-text-field-wrapper {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Note that as mentioned above, adding ::ng-deep to the start can affect elements outside your intended target. One way to avoid this is to wrap the element you want to target in a div, assign that div a class and add the class selector before the :ng-deep to only target elements within that div.